# Javascript bookmarklet: how to replace URL parts?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a Javascript bookmarklet, which would extract a numeric ID from an URL:

```
   http://site-1/script-1.php?ID=12345678&other-params
```

and then redirect the browser to a new URL:

```
   http://site-2/script-2.php?id=12345678
```

I've searched net for bookmarklet examples and I have 2 questions please:

1) Do I need to place my JS-code inside a **void**?

```
javascript:void(XXX);
```

What does **void** mean in this context?

2) Should I use **location.href** for reading the old URL and assigning a new constructed URL? I'm asking because I've seen many strange pieces of code, like **String(location.href)** etc. - like it needs some *casting* to String (does it?)

**UPDATE:** I've tried the following code, but nothing happens in Chrome unfortunately, when I'm on the old page and click my bookmarklet (hoping to navigate to the new page):

```
javascript:void (
    if ( var match = location.search.match(/id=(\d+)/i) ) 
        location = 'http://site-2/script-2.php?id=' + match[1];
)
```

(I've added line-breaks above and yes I'm trying to use a single "=")

**UPDATE 2:** My 2nd try - just trying to display a new URL:

```
javascript:void (
    var match = location.search.match(/ID=(\d+)/);
    alert('http://site-2/script-2.php?id=' + match[1]);
)
```

but still nothing happens, when I click the bookmark at the bookmarks bar. And I see in Google Chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If your bookmarklet returns a value so that after all code is run, the url could be read as: `javascript:%somestring%` the browser will display that string in the browser window. So `void()` is just a safeguard ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) `...The void operator evaluates the given expression and then returns undefined...`) against accidently overwriding the document. This means, if you're careful you don't need void.

2) No need to cast it, as it will happen automatically if you don't provide a string value.

---

My bookmarklet template:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){
  // do stuff but do not return anything
}());">something</a>
```

---

Update:

```
javascript:(function () {
  var match = window.location.href.match(/ID=(\d+)/);
  if (match.length > 0) {
    alert('http://site-2/script-2.php?id=' + match[1]);
    // or after debugging: window.location = 'http://site-2/script-2.php?id=' + match[1];
  }
}());
```

Comment: `var` in an if condition is invalid syntax ;)   (declare match before the if, then use it)

Comment: Use `match` instead of `search`. (location.match)

Comment: Thanks, I've actually wanted location.search.match(). I've updated my code - still no alert popup is being shown.

Comment: Thank you, but same problem: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4775/discussion-between-yoshi-and-alexander-farber)